# dvisvgm conversion renders differently on browser than on inkscape

Tags: svg, dvisvgm

I'm converting some TikZ pictures in SVG file with standalone class. To achieve that, I'm compiling with :

```
latex \jobname.tex
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 \jobname.dvi
```

Although with easy tikzpicture, there is a difference with square root between browser rendering and Inkscape or Gimp. How to solve that ? Without the `font-format=woff2` option, svg's render the same wrong output.

Here a MWE :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] {$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the differences with images :

[image: Browser]
[image: Inkscape]

dvisvgm is version 3.0.4 and I run with MikTex on windows.

Comment: Try `--no-fonts` instead of `--font-format=woff2` if the importing application does not support SVG fonts. This embeds font elements as plain paths.

Comment: @AlexG It fixed the rendering ofc but texts won't be searchable anymore :( ...

Comment: As a fix/workaround you could import PDF instead of SVG in Inkscape ([source](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/how-do-i-open-a-svg-with-embedded-fonts-in-inkscape/)). Though I am unsure whether this creates searchable text.